# What is the difference?

Tags: embedded, control-system

What is the difference between embedded systems and control systems?
I have to choose my future career and I don't now the difference.

Comment: An op-amp amplifier is a control system but it certainly is not an embedded system. Start from this and work up.

Comment: Nothing to do with electronic design. Question should be closed.

Comment: (oversimplification) embedded systems is computer programming, control systems is differential equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Control systems generate an output based on some input, a set of tuning parameters, and a setpoint. One example is the heating/cooling thermostat in your home.

One of the more common control systems is called PID, for proportional, integral, and derivative.

[image]

The control system tries to keep the feedback value from the process as close to the set point as possible, without overshoot or undershoot.

[image]

In the past, control systems were completely implemented in hardware.  I have designed them using a separate op-amp for each term, P, I and D, and used potentiometers to control the coefficients.

Embedded computers are general purpose computing platforms that feature a microcontroller (CPU, memory, and I/O).  They are very general and can be used for anything from controlling a microwave to being the guts of your smart phone.

You can completely build a PID control system using an microcontroller.

One such use is a automobile cruise control.  I designed one of these using a Motorola 8-bit microcontroller (HC05 for those that member) about 25 years ago.

So an embedded system is a general purpose (but small) computer, and a control system is a very special piece of hardware (or firmware, implemented in as an embedded system).

As far as a career choice, control systems would be a very narrow field.  Embedded systems would be much more general, probably more interesting, and if you want, you could still built a control system using a microcontroller.

Comment: Gah, you beat me. For sure, control systems only makes money for the techs out in the plants with the tools and know-how to take it apart and put it back together in sweaty conditions. Control systems, for me, only constituted 3 semester hours and is pretty straightforward for just about any EE. If the OP specializes in embedded, they should still be able to accomplish all tasks required to design a working distributed control system.

Comment: thanks sir for your great answer ,I have to choose between two departments 'electrical energy and control systems' or 'communication and electronics' what do you advice me ? for me I like all electrical things I find all of them interesting

Comment: @mr.Arrow  I'd go with "communication and electronics". "electrical energy and control systems" sounds like a lot of power plant stuff and *big* motors. That was the most boring EE course I took. Labs with wires the size of your wrist (well, almost). You can probably take one or two control theory classes as an elective.

Comment: Actually the discipline of control system engineering is *Huge* encompassing a vast number of applications - electronics and controls for industrial plants are just some of the many areas that can be considered. A good controls engineer knows the physics of the systems they are trying to control, how to model them, and how to modify their behavior using a variety of control methods, most typically relying on sensing and feedback. In my career I've worked controls for medical, aerospace and industrial laser systems. It's a challenging and exciting career choice!